# how to automatically detect encoding httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, encoding, httpwebrequest

I am sending a lot of requests to many websites in different languages.

Is it possible to automatically detect the encoding of the website? just like the browser does it...

I've tried to use

```
response.CharacterSet
```

but it seems not to work...

thanks...

Comment: The browser doesn't detect the _server_ language. It send an `Accept-Language` header in the HTTP request.

Comment: but how does the browser detect the current encoding to read the response from the website?

Comment: This is done by reading the `Content-Type` header: it can specify the charset. For instance: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: for example I am requesting this RSS feed: http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss2.xml it is in Hebrew and according to the <xml tag it is Windows-1255. but can I know it before I read the stream from the website so I can read it just one time with the currect encoding

Comment: The content type is text/xml; and the encoding is specified in the XML itself: `encoding="Windows-1255"`. A lame encoding to use in 2013...